# Is there a way to use string concatenation/interpolation in perl using the HTMLMail package?

Tags: html, string, perl

I have a somewhat unique situation where I am using the HTMLMail package in perl to color text in a few of my strings.  However, in doing this I have realized that I'm stumped in regards to inserting a variable into this colored string.  Below is my example:

`my $text = '<FONT COLOR="#AF0000">These programs: $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1] can't load!</FONT COLOR>';`

Where `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`

Are the variables I'm trying to insert into the string.

When I've tried separating them with a combination of quotations and periods, I get an error detailing that I need to include an explicit package name at the next line.  If anyone more experienced with perl can point me in the right direction to a solution that would still keep all text and variables colored, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Use double quotes (or `qq{}` or a heredoc since the string has embedded double quotes) to get variable interpolation. See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators

Answer (score 1):

Your single quoted string has an unescaped single quote in it. As @Shawn noted in the comments, you need double quotes to interpolate variables, and you want to have `"` as data. Use the generalized quoting for double quotes, `qq()` to get around that:

```
my $text = qq(<FONT COLOR="#AF0000">These programs: $ARGV[0] $ARGV[1] can't load!</FONT COLOR>);
```

If there are other errors, show us the actual error message.